# Extjs Scroll bar automatically scroll down preventing me from scrolling to the top

Tags: css, extjs, scrollbar

I have a problem with the scrollbar of my grid panel. When I scroll to the bottom and I try to scroll up again at one point the scroll bar automatically scroll down preventing me from scrolling to the top of the list.

[image]

I tried to set the layout 'fit', or give to the panel a certain width and height size, but nothing of this solutions work.

This is my code:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'listView',

    requires: [
        'Traccar.view.ListController',
        'Ext.ux.grid.SubTable'
    ],

    controller: 'list',
    store : 'MyStore',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoscroll:false,

    id: 'listId',
    tbar: {
        componentCls: 'toolbar-header-style',
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'button',
            disabled: true,
            tooltipType: 'title'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'tbtext',
            html: 'List',
            baseCls: 'x-panel-header-title-default'
        }, {
            xtype: 'tbfill',
            disabled: false
        }, {
            xtype: 'settingsMenu',
            reference: 'settingsMenu',
            disabled: false,
            enableToggle: false
        }]
    },
    columns: {
        items: [{
            text: Strings.sharedName,
            dataIndex: 'name',
            filter: 'string',
            flex: 1
        },{
            text: 'Devices',
            flex: 0.2,
            renderer: function(a,b,record){
                    var bla = Ext.Array.filter(
                         Ext.getStore('Devices').data.items,
                         function(r) { return r.get('activeItemFromStore').includes(record.get('id'));}
                    );
                    return bla.length;
            }
        }]
    },
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            expandbody: 'onExpandbody',
            collapsebody: 'onCollapsebody',
        },
        getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, p, store) {
            if (record.getData().attributes.color) {
                //return 'bigHeader centerlist-row-' + record.getData().attributes.color.replace('#','')
                return 'centerlist-row-' + record.getData().attributes.color.replace('#','')
            }else{
                //return 'bigHeader centerlist-row-default';
                return 'centerlist-row-default';
            }
        }
    },

    plugins: {
     ptype: 'subtable',
     association: 'devices',
     expandOnDblClick: false,
     headerWidth: 28,
     hideHeaders: true,
     //rowBodyTpl: ['<table class="bigFont ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-subtable"',
     rowBodyTpl: ['<table class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-subtable"',
             '{%',
                 'this.owner.renderTable(out, values);',
             '%}',
             '</tbody></table>'
     ],
     columns: [
     {
         flex: 1,
         text: Strings.sharedName,
         dataIndex: 'name'
     },{
          text: Strings.deviceLastUpdate,
          dataIndex: 'lastUpdate',
          type: 'date',
          renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('d.m.Y H:i:s')
       },{
        text: Strings.sendMessage,
        dataIndex: 'attributes.message'
     }],

     getAssociatedRecords: function(record) {
         return Ext.Array.filter(
                     Ext.getStore('Devices').data.items,
                     function(r) { return r.get('activeItemFromStore').includes(record.get('id'));}
         );
     },
     renderTable: function(out, rowValues) {
             var me = this,
                 columns = me.columns,
                 numColumns = columns.length,
                 associatedRecords = me.getAssociatedRecords(rowValues.record),
                 recCount = associatedRecords.length,
                 rec, column, i, j, value;

             out.push('><tbody><thead>');
             for (j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
                 out.push('<th class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-subtable-header">', columns[j].text || columns[j].dataIndex, '</th>');
             }
             out.push('</thead>');
             if ( associatedRecords.length > 1){
                 associatedRecords = associatedRecords.descSortBy(function(o){ return o.data.lastUpdate });
             }

             for (i = 0; i < recCount; i++) {
                 rec = associatedRecords[i];
                 out.push('<tr>');
                 for (j = 0; j < numColumns; j++) {
                     column = columns[j];

                     // attributes as dataindex
                     if ( column.dataIndex.includes(".")){
                        var a = column.dataIndex.split(".");
                        value = rec.get(a[0])[a[1]]
                     }else{
                       value = rec.get(column.dataIndex);
                     }

                     if (column.renderer && column.renderer.call) {
                         value = column.renderer.call(column.scope || me, value, {}, rec);
                     }
                     //out.push('<td class="bigFont ' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-subtable-cell"');
                     out.push('<td class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-subtable-cell"');
                     if (column.width != null) {
                         out.push(' style="width:' + column.width + 'px"');
                     }
                    out.push('><div class="' + Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'grid-cell-inner">', value, '</div></td>');
                 }
                 out.push('</tr>');
             }

         }
    },
    listeners: {
          rowdblclick: 'onEnterMessageWindow'
    }
});
```

How can I fix it?

I made some debugging and the problem seems to be related to the `plugins: {...}`

Comment: May you provide fiddle sample?

Comment: It is very hard to fix the bug from the fragment of code, may you reproduce the bug in fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Comment: On which browser you are facing issue. Most probably these issues are mostly reproduced on IE browser

Comment: I tested on chrome and firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the problem and the solution: **the problem is related to the expanding row feature present in my grid panel**.

The `plugins: {...}` mentioned in the question, in fact, managed this functionality (subtable) but I didn't know exactly which part of the code inside it generates the problem and why.

By making more deep research, I found out that expanding row causes scroll issues.

references:

- https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/286b
- https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?286536-Expanding-row-causes-scroll-issues-on-tablet&p=1047739&viewfull=1
- https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?466458-Grid-vertical-scroll-bar-problem-during-expand-collapse-of-a-node

The only way to fix this problem so is to set **bufferedRenderer** and **runInViewport** to false:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'listView',

    bufferedRenderer: false,
    runInViewport: false,


    requires: [
        'Traccar.view.ListController',
        'Ext.ux.grid.SubTable'
    ],

    ...
```

Comment: I'm having users with this issue, but I'm unable to reproduce it and think it might have been the version of Chrome we have deployed on our intranet. Looking into what those 2 configs do, I can't find "runInViewport" in any of the Ext docs -- where is this documented?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix this issue on my side with the following override (ExtJS 6.2.2), see the added line on the bottom:

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer, {
    refreshScroller: function(view, scrollRange) {
        var scroller = view.getScrollable();
        if (scroller) {
            // Ensure the scroller viewport element size is up to date if it needs to be told (touch scroller)
            if (scroller.setElementSize) {
                scroller.setElementSize();
            }
            // Ensure the scroller knows about content size
            scroller.setSize({
                x: view.headerCt.getTableWidth(),
                y: scrollRange
            });
            // In a locking assembly, stretch the yScroller
            if (view.lockingPartner) {
                this.scroller.setSize({
                    x: 0,
                    y: scrollRange
                });
            }
            
            scroller.scrollTo(null, this.scrollTop); // added
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On my end it was caused by

```
hideHeaders: true
```

I turned it off and removed the column texts to reproduce the same looking and the bug vanished